# RoR submitting object for approval and only processing payment on approval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, ruby-on-rails-3.2, payment-gateway

I have a fairly generic question I am looking to get some advice on.

I am creating a basic Ruby on Rails job application where users can submit jobs and apply for other positons.

What I would like to happen is that when a user submits a job it enters a holding pool (say an awaiting_approval table) that then awaits admin approval.

On admin approval I would like the job to leave the 'holding pool' and push into my main jobs table. I would also like at the same time for payment to be taken from the user.

I am keen to not process payment details myself so would be interested to know if anyone has ever managed to implement something like this through Paypal or another payment provider?

Any advice on how I can achieve this setup would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan Bates did [a whole bunch of screencasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=23) on integrating various payment services in Rails. He includes PayPal, ActiveMerchant, Stripe and Spree. It's worth giving them a watch, as even with libraries like ActiveMerchant there are a lot of little details to be aware of.

My personal choice would be [Stripe](https://stripe.com), given its simplicity and cost.

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts are correct about not processing your own payments. Rolling your own PCI-compliant payment system is not trivial. Read up on security standards here:
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/merchants/

I haven't had a chance to use it myself but the ActiveMerchant gem is the most popular way to communicate with payment gateways. It's supports PayPal as well as a bunch of other gateways:
https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant